# Get TemplateRepeatIndex out of TemplateBeginRepeat

Tags: 2009, dwt

I have the code above in a DWT and what I need is to put in the "X" the number of elements that I have. So the final TemplateRepeatIndex + 1 and it should be in the DWT if it is possible.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

```
<ul data-orbit="" class="adapt-story-slider orbit-slides-container" style="height: 521px;">
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.decoratedGames" -->
    <li data-orbit-slide="headline-@@TemplateRepeatIndex@@" 
    </li>
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
</ul>

<div class="orbit-slide-number">
  <span>1</span> of <span> **X** </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to do it is to add a C# Fragment or .NET TBB to calculate the number of elements you will be rendering in your DWT and push it in a Package Variable so that you can access it.

```
<div class="orbit-slide-number">
  <span>1</span> of <span> @@NumberOfElements@@ </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I'm afraid this is the only solution, but I was wondering if there could be other one in a DWT.
Anyway thanks.

Comment: As of 2011 SP1 you can use the function "CollectionLength()" in DWT to get your "X": https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/BuiltInFunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates.  Dylan blogged about using it here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/tag/dreamweaver-templating

Comment: +1 to Nick's comment, of course CollectionLength() will be a nice DWT solution

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov: please post your comment as a separate answer.

Comment: The question is tagged with 2009.  My answer is for 2011 SP1.